# Compressing vector with POCO (c++)

Tags: c++, stl, poco

The [POCO Library](http://pocoproject.org/) requires an istream for input and ostream for output to compress data using its zlib wrapper. I have data in a std::vector(unsigned char) and would like to compress this data into another std::vector(unsigned char). Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Most probably offers stream adaptors. If not, then most probably Boost does. Read the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that this is the most efficient way, but as a start I'd try this:

```
typedef unsigned char uc;
typedef vector<uc> v;
void Doit(const v& in, v& out)
{
   ostringstream outStream;
   DeflatingOutputStream compressor(outStream, DeflatingStreamBuf::STREAM_GZIP);
   copy(in.begin(), in.end(), ostream_iterator<uc>(compressor));
   compressor.close();
   string outStr(outStream.str());
   out.assign(outStr.begin(), outStr.end());
}
```

I suspect this copies the data twice, unnecessarily. First, the call to ostringstream::str() makes a copy, and next std::vector::assign() makes a copy.

@Alf P. Steinbach had an excellent suggestion -- use Boost stream adapters. If you have `boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream` available to you, you could try this:

```
typedef unsigned char uc;
typedef vector<uc> v;

void Doit(const v& in, v& out)
{
   filtering_ostream outStream(back_inserter(out));
   DeflatingOutputStream compressor(outStream, DeflatingStreamBuf::STREAM_GZIP);
   std::copy(in.begin(), in.end(), ostream_iterator<uc>(compressor));
   compressor.close();
   outStream.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use normal `istream` and `ostream` objects and use the [`pubsetbuf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/pubsetbuf/) method of [their `streambuf`s](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/rdbuf/) to set the internal buffer of the stream to the internal buffer of the vector.

In this scenario you would have to make sure that the vector receiving the output has enough space available. Since the ostream would write directly to the buffer, no automatic resizing would happen.